# which one is more efficient for stdin input

Tags: python

I am trying to input from stdin.

I think there are many ways to perform it.
Among them, I want to use one of below two ways.
(if there is more efficient alternative, let me know)

first,

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()
while line != "" :
    # do something
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

second,

```
for line in stdin :
    # do something
```

which one is more efficient way?
if there is no difference, which one is more Pythonic or closer to standard?

sorry for my poor English.

I looking forward your answer

Answer (score 1):

The second (`for line in sys.stdin`) is more efficient, more DRY, and more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iter:

```
from sys import stdin

for line in iter(stdin.readline, "\n"):
    # do something
    print(line)
```

Or with raw_input:

```
for line in iter(raw_input, ""): # python3 -> for line in iter(input, ""):
    # do something
    print(line)
```

Your loop won't break using `while line != ""`

```
In [2]: line = stdin.readline()


In [3]: while line != "" :
   ...:     print(repr(line))
   ...:     line = stdin.readline()
   ...:     
'\n'

'\n'

'\n'

'\n'
```

I would use raw_input or input if you are actually taking user input, I also doubt efficiency is going to be an issue whatever you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The second `for line in stdin` is more efficient, because it just has to do less.

One way to get a quantitative glance at performance is to look at the bytecode:

```
In [1]: def a():
   ...:     line = sys.stdin.readline()
   ...:     while line != "":
   ...:         line = sys.stdin.readline()
   ...:

In [2]: def b():
   ...:     for line in stdin:
   ...:         pass
   ...:
```

You can use the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module for that:

```
In [3]: import dis
```

This is the first function:

```
In [4]: dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sys)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (stdin)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (readline)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (line)

  3          15 SETUP_LOOP              31 (to 49)
        >>   18 LOAD_FAST                0 (line)
             21 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
             24 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             27 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       48

  4          30 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sys)
             33 LOAD_ATTR                1 (stdin)
             36 LOAD_ATTR                2 (readline)
             39 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             42 STORE_FAST               0 (line)
             45 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           18
        >>   48 POP_BLOCK
        >>   49 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             52 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is the second one, it has about 50% of the instructions:

```
In [5]: dis.dis(b)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 17)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (stdin)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 16)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (line)

  3          13 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   16 POP_BLOCK
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE

In [6]:
```

Note that the first needs to make attribute lookups, `LOAD_ATTR`, and a function call, `CALL_FUNCTION`, which are expensive and absent in the second bytecode excerpt.